# Save Attachments From New Email

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to use Outlook VBA to check all my emails on startup, and whenever I receive a new email, to see if the email subject is "Sample Daily Data Pull". If the email subject matches, I want outlook to save the attachment to a specified network drive folder. Here is the code I have:

In "ThisOutlookSession"

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    If Item.Subject = "Sample Daily Data Pull" Then
    Call SaveAttachmentsToDisk
    Else
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I also have the following code in a module:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String

sSaveFolder = "N:\SampleFilePath\"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next
End Sub
```

This is my first time working in Outlook VBA, so my apologies if it's something very basic and obvious. Not really sure what is going wrong as I'm not getting any error messages. All I know is that the the macro is not saving attachments on my network drive as it should be.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please discard `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` and all the error handling code.  This type of code is never helpful during development and would require substantial modification to be appropriate for a live system.

Comment: You are not checking emails on startup.  You are creating an event handler at startup.  That event handler (`inboxItems_ItemAdd`) is activated whenever a new email arrives in your default Inbox.  This may seem picky but code to check existing emails on startup would be very different.

Comment: Your question implies something is not working as you wish but you do not tell us what is going wrong.

Comment: @TonyDallimore At the time that I open up Outlook, would the system not recognize any emails received since my last session as "new emails" and run the macro? If not I guess I'll have to look into that as well. As far as what the problem is with the code right now. I'm not really sure and don't really know how to test it either. The only thing I really know at this point is that the code is not placing the attachments into the network folder as it should be.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Thanks for the note about the error handling, I've removed all the relevant code.

Comment: My concern was the expression "... check all my emails on startup ..." rather than "... check all my **new emails** on startup ...".  There are four distinct ways of selecting emails for processing.  (1) Process emails selected by user. (2) Check every email in a folder and process as appropriate. (3) Process emails selected by a rule.  (4) Use an event to select every new email and process as appropriate.  Yes, emails which reached the server since you last closed Outlook are new.  I have encountered people who think they can mixed (2) and (4) and was concerned that was what you thought.

Comment: I am please you have removed the error handling.  Do you understand why I think it is bad practice?

Comment: @TonyDallimore Thank you for the clarification. As long as it checks all the new emails I'm happy :)

Comment: @TonyDallimore To be honest I don't understand why, as of right now I'm just trying to figure out why the macros does not work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work for me because of:

`Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items`

Outlook saves mail items, calendar items, tasks and other such information in files it calls **Stores**.  You can have several stores each of which will have an Inbox.  I am a home user with two email accounts.  I did a default installation of Outlook then used a wizard to add an account for each of my email addresses.  The result is I had three stores:

- Outlook Data File
- MyName@myisp.com
- MyName@gmail.com

“Outlook Data File” is the default store and contains the default Inbox but new emails are placed in the Inboxes in the other two stores.  To test if you have the same problem, open Outlook, open the VBA Editor, type the following into your Immediate Window and press [Return].

```
    ? Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Name
```

On my system, this statement outputs “Outlook Data File” because that store contains the default Inbox.  If I want to have an event handler for new emails I need to have:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set InboxItems = Session.Folders("MyName@myisp.com").Folders("Inbox").Items
End Sub
```

This is someone shorter than your macro, which I will explain later, but the key difference is I am naming the Inbox I wish to monitor.  If the Inbox that receives your new emails is not Outlook’s default Inbox, you will have to name the folder containing the Inbox you wish to monitor.

Why is my macro so much shorter than yours?

```
 Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
 Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
```

You are already within Outlook so these statements are redundant.

You could replace:

```
Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

by

```
Set objectNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

But you do not have to.  The only `GetNamespace` is under `Application` so the qualification is optional.  The only qualification that I know to be non-optional is `Outlook.Folder` and `Scripting.Folder`.  If you write `Folder` within Outlook it assumes you want one of its folders.  If you want to refer to a disk folder you must say so.

You have:

```
Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

I have used `Session`.  The documentation states that `Namespace` and `Session` are identical.  I prefer `Session` but most people seem to prefer `Namespace`.  Your choice.

If you are references the correct Inbox, we need to look further for the cause of your problem.

The next possible issue is `If Item.Subject = "Sample Daily Data Pull"`.  This requires `Item.Subject` be exactly equal to `"Sample Daily Data Pull"`.  An extra space or a lower case letter and they are not equal.

Next, I suggest adding a statement at the top of each of procedure to give:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
Debug.Assert False
  :    :    :
Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Debug.Assert False
  :    :    :
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Debug.Assert False
  :    :    :
```

Many programming languages have an **Assertion statement**; this is VBA’s version.  It allows the programmer to assert that something will be true.  Execution will stop if the assertion is false.  I find `Debug.Assert False` invaluable during testing.  `Debug.Assert False` will always be false so execution will always stop.  This is an easy way to test that `Application_Startup`, `inboxItems_ItemAdd` and `SaveAttachmentsToDisk` are being executed.

Try the above suggestions.  If they fail to find a problem, we will have to try something else.

**Error Handling**

In your original posting, you had:

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
     :        :       :

     :        :       :

ExitNewItem:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
```

You will often see code like this but I have never seen a justification for it.

If an error occurs during development, this code will result in the error number and description being displayed and the routine exited.  How is this helpful?  It leaves you to guess from the error description which statement failed.  If you omit all the error code, execution stops on the faulty statement.  There is no guessing as to which statement was in error.  If you can fix the error, you can click F5 and restart with the previously faulty statement.  Even if you cannot fix and restart, you have a better understanding of the situation.

For a live system, I have difficulty in imagining anything less user friendly than an error resulting in display of a cryptic error message and the macro terminating.

For a live system, you want something like:

```
Dim ErrNum As Long
Dim ErrDesc As String

On Error Resume Next
Statement that might fail
ErrNum = Err.Num
ErrDesc = Err.Description
On Error GoTo 0
If ErrNum > 0 Then
  ' For each possible value for ErrNum, code to provide user friendly
  ' description of what has gone wrong and how to fix it.
End If
```

VBA is not the ideal language for writing code that fails gracefully but with care you can create some very acceptable error handling code.

Comment: Thank you Tony! You guesses right that the error was coming from the fact that my Outlook store was not the default one. I learned a lot from this post, thanks again!